# How to group_by different attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a timeline for `@challenges`. For those challenges that have a `:deadline` I want them to be organized on the timeline according to their `:deadline` and for those challenge that have a `:date_started` I want them to be organized on the timeline according to their `:date_started`.

If a challenge has a `:deadline` then `date_started` is `nil` and vice versa.

### example

```
2016
  February
    CHALLENGE 1 (Deadline: 1st)
    CHALLENGE 2 (Date_Started: 3rd)
    CHALLENGE 3 (Deadline: 18th)
```

### controller

```
@challenges = current_user.challenges
@challenges_timeline = @challenges.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_year + t.date_started.beginning_of_year }
```

### view

```
<% @challenges_timeline.sort.each do |year, challenges| %>
  <%= year.strftime('%Y') %>
  <% challenges.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_month + t.date_started.beginning_of_month }.sort.each do |month, challenges| %>
    <%= month.strftime('%B') %>
    <% for challenge in challenges %>
      <% if challenge.deadline.present? %>
        <%= challenge.deadline %>:  <%= challenge.action %>
      <% end %>
      <% if challenge.date_started.present? %>
        <%= challenge.date_started %>:  <%= challenge.action %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your schema:

If the two dates negate each other, perhaps you should have just one date field, and another field to show whether the date is the beginning or the end. That would allow you to group on the database level, saving some processing time.

2. Add instance method

A simple instance method such as

```
def timeline_date
  deadline || date_started
end
```

would allow simple grouping such as

```
challenges.group_by { |c| c.timeline_date.beginning_of_month }
```

3. Use `||` directly in the `group_by` block.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't understand what you mean by change your schema. I tried step 2 and 3, but then that makes them group_by two different timeline instead of fitting all in one. And when I say `date_started` that is just an example. My intention is to use something a little more complicated where `ongoing` challenges aren't just listed the day they started, but the days they're committed to which looks something like this: `committed.map do |day| Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) end`

Comment: These are not steps, rather different approaches to solve. Not sure why are you getting "two different timelines" when you group. Also, it seems to me that you haven't properly decoupled the business logic from the presentation logic there. Too much logic you are trying to push in the view/controller.

Comment: Changing your schema means changing how your DB tables look like. It seems that having a single date field, rather than two which are mutually exclusive, would be a better solution.